# Error 3780 Columna referencia

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Cordial saludo, el presente mensaje es para consultar un error que estoy teniendo en mysql, consiste en que quiero relacionar 2 tablas Proveedor y clientes con dos tablas llamadas dirección y teléfono, pero al parecer cuando las relaciono con la variable foránea me sale el siguiente error que no comprendo.

```
ERROR: Error 3780: Referencing column 'COD_DIRECCION' and referenced column 'COD_DIRECCION' in foreign key constraint 'COD_DIRECCION' are incompatible.
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`PROVEEDOR` 
        ADD CONSTRAINT `COD_DIRECCION`
          FOREIGN KEY (`COD_DIRECCION`)
          REFERENCES `mydb`.`DIRECCION` (`COD_DIRECCION`)
          ON DELETE NO ACTION
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
        ADD CONSTRAINT `COD_TELEFONO`
          FOREIGN KEY (`COD_TELEFONO`)
          REFERENCES `mydb`.`TELEFONO` (`COD_TELEFONO`)
          ON DELETE NO ACTION
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed
```

[image: adjunto imagen que relaciona lo que he formulado]

Adicionalmente adjunto el código que me genera MySQL al intentar sincronizar el modelo, luego de previamente haber hecho el diseño de la base de datos:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Synchronization
-- Generated: 2022-09-22 10:09
-- Model: New Model
-- Version: 1.0
-- Project: Name of the project
-- Author: 1017249739

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

ALTER SCHEMA `mydb`  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_bin ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`CLIENTE` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `NOMBRE` `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `COD_TELEFONO` `COD_TELEFONO` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `COD_DIRECCION` `COD_DIRECCION` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`DIRECCION` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `COD_DIRECCION` `COD_DIRECCION` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CIUDAD` `CIUDAD` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `COMUNA` `COMUNA` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CALLE` `CALLE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `NUMERO` `NUMERO` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`TELEFONO` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `COD_TELEFONO` `COD_TELEFONO` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CELULAR1` `CELULAR1` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CELULAR2` `CELULAR2` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `TELEFONO1` `TELEFONO1` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `TELEFONO2` `TELEFONO2` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`PRODUCTOS` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `NOMBRE` `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `PRECIO_UNITARIO` `PRECIO_UNITARIO` DECIMAL NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`STOCK` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`CATEGORIA_PRODUCTOS` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CATEGORIA` `CATEGORIA` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `DESCRIPCION` `DESCRIPCION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`VENTA` 
COLLATE = utf8_bin ,
CHANGE COLUMN `CODIGO_FACTURA` `CODIGO_FACTURA` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `PRECIO_UNIDAD` `PRECIO_UNIDAD` DECIMAL NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `PRECIO_TOTAL` `PRECIO_TOTAL` DECIMAL NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `DESCUENTO` `DESCUENTO` DECIMAL NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `PRECIO_FINAL` `PRECIO_FINAL` DECIMAL NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`PROVEEDOR` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `COD_DIRECCION`
  FOREIGN KEY (`COD_DIRECCION`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`DIRECCION` (`COD_DIRECCION`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `COD_TELEFONO`
  FOREIGN KEY (`COD_TELEFONO`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`TELEFONO` (`COD_TELEFONO`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`CLIENTE` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `COD_DIRECCION`
  FOREIGN KEY (`COD_DIRECCION`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`DIRECCION` (`COD_DIRECCION`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `COD_TELEFONO`
  FOREIGN KEY (`COD_TELEFONO`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`TELEFONO` (`COD_TELEFONO`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`PRODUCTOS` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `ID_PRODUCTOCATEGORIA`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PRODUCTO`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`CATEGORIA_PRODUCTOS` (`ID_PRODUCTO`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `ID_PRODUCTOSTOCK`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PRODUCTO`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`STOCK` (`ID_PRODUCTO`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `NIP_PROVEEDOR`
  FOREIGN KEY (`NIP_PROVEEDOR`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`PROVEEDOR` (`NIP`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`VENTA` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `NIP_CLIENTE`
  FOREIGN KEY (`NIP_CLIENTE`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`CLIENTE` (`NIP`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `ID_PRODUCTO`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PRODUCTO`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`PRODUCTOS` (`ID_PRODUCTO`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

''Actualización:

Las tablas y datos los he creado directamente desde un EER Diagram.
A continuación mostraré como he fijado cada uno de los elementos de las tablas:
Para Cliente:
[image: db-cliente]

Para Proveedor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dirección que solo se creo con las siguientes variables:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realizando la aplicación del comentario valido del post de A. Cedano, me sale lo siguiente al escribir el comando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta mostrarnos cómo está hecha la tabla dirección. Idealmente, podrías incluir el CREATE TABLE de proveedor y dirección, por favor

Comment: hola Alfabravo, agradezco tu respuesta, eh como tal no tengo el código de creado porque lo hice desde un ERR DIAGRAMA puedo facilitar, en la actualización del post, cómo hice la relación de los foreign keys.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las columnas que participan en una relación de llave foránea **deben ser exactamente del mismo tipo y tener las mismas características que la columna en la tabla referente**. Me parece que el mensaje de error es bastante elocuente, te está diciendo **que las columnas son incompatibles**. Es muy probable que el error se deba a que no son iguales. Como bien dice @Alfabravo, muéstranos los `CREATE TABLE` de todas las tablas implicadas. Para obtener dicho código puedes escribir una consulta parecida a esta: **`SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;`**

Comment: Apuesto mis dos frijolitos a que en proveedor, el campo no tiene el `NOT NULL` pero pues, no lo sabemos :D

Comment: vale no sé si con la actualización del post, soy un poco más claro jejej, estoy nuevo en este mundo y ofrezco disculpas por mi ignorancia en el tema, pero trataré de replicar también el aporte de A. Cedano

Comment: Aparte de lo que te estan diciendo, porque son varchar??? si son codigos, son numeros, sin por lo menos enteros... o vas a guardar cadenas ahi?

Comment: la idea es que se guarden cadenas,los códigos no son netamente numérico

Comment: Por favor, evita las capturas de pantalla, pon el texto que te arrojan los `SHOW CREATE TABLE` tal cual, como texto plano, así es más fácil para analizar.